# How to create a dynamic URL by a previous scenario response in Karate DSL

Tags: karate

I'd like to create my next URL by getting a specifically information of my previous scenario response. Examples:

Scenario: Get test 1

```
Given       url 'http://UrlOfMyTest/ApiTest/'
And         header Content-Type = 'application/json'
And         header Authorization = token
When        method get
Then        status 200
And         print 'The Response of "information" is: ', response.objects[0]."name of the field"
```

Now, In my next scenario I need the dynamic information of my "response.objects[0].name of the field" to fill out the rest of my URL in Scenario 2

Scenario2: Get test 2

```
Given       url 'http://UrlOfMyTest/ApiTest/"plus_Information_Of_Previous_Scenario_Response"'
And         header Content-Type = 'application/json'
And         header Authorization = token
When        method get
Then        status 200
```